# Trying to delete mail using node-imap

Tags: node.js, imap

Trying to delete email in **node.js** using **[node-imap](https://github.com/mscdex/node-imap)** module.

I open the **INBOX** in read/write mode:

```
imap.openBox('INBOX', false, cb);
```

I then **fetch** all the messages:

```
var f = imap.seq.fetch("1:"+box.messages.total, {
      bodies: ['HEADER.FIELDS (FROM TO SUBJECT DATE)','TEXT'],
      struct: true
    });
```

I **flag** the mail to be deleted:

```
msg.on('end', function() {

    imap.seq.addFlags(seqno, '\\Deleted', function(err) { } );
  });
```

I **close** the mailbox with **autopurge** set to true

```
imap.closeBox(true);
```

But this doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const mailBox = new imap({
  host: "imap.gmail.com",
  password: GMAIL_PASSWORD,
  port: 993,
  tls: true,
  user: GMAIL
});

mailBox.once("error", console.error);
mailBox.once("ready", () => {
  mailBox.openBox("INBOX", false, (error, box) => {
    if (error) throw error;

    mailBox.search(
      [
        "UNSEEN",
        ["SUBJECT", "xxx"],
        ["FROM", "no-reply@xxx.xxx"]
      ],
      (error, results) => {
        if (error) throw error;

        for (const uid of results) {
          const mails = mailBox.fetch(uid, {
            bodies: ""
            // markSeen: true
          });
          mails.once("end", () => mailBox.end());

          mails.on("message", (message, seq) => {
            message.on("body", stream => {
              let buffer = "";
              stream.on("data", chunk => (buffer += chunk.toString("utf8")));
              stream.once("end", () => mailBox.addFlags(uid, "Deleted"));
            });
          });
        }
      }
    );
  });
});

mailBox.connect();
```

Answer (score 3):

`imap.setFlags()` works with UIDs. `imap.seq.setFlags()` works with sequence numbers. Since it seems like you're trying to pass a sequence number, you should use the latter function instead.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but still not working. i updated by question with correct function, thanks for pointing that out.